# Any idea why gulp-uglify won't minimize my ES6 javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, gulp, minify, babeljs

This isn't a priority at all, but this has been bugging me for a while. I hate to even post it on here because I'm completely confused, but maybe someone else will understand it.

A few things to note before I get into the spiel:

1. This is from a Udemy course, not my project.
2. I have a general understanding of Gulp at best.
3. I know basic javascript, but don't really know much of the ES6 features.
4. For this Udemy course, Babel is used so ES6 outputs to ES5 for browsers that don't currently support ES6.
5. For this Udemy course, JQuery was mainly used, and the Javascript files were broken into chunks. Then each chunk was imported into a main JS file. Kind of making SCSS partials, importing them into a main SCSS file, then the CSS file shows ALL the code

I hope this is all clear.

I've identified 4 areas of code in the javascript that are causing the issue, that are making it so my javascript code can't be minified using the gulp-uglify task. I think the ES6...term? (not sure what to properly call it)..."Class" is causing the issue. And these are all Constructor functions.

If I get rid of those 4 Constructor functions, I'm able to gulp-uglify the file without any issues...but of course I need that code.

I'm only going to show the code from the "live" file, because I'll have to most likely alter that to get gulp-uglify to work

I hope this isn't confusing, because I'm confused even typing this all up.

```
class MobileMenu {
constructor() {
    this.siteHeader = __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_jquery___default.a(".site-header");
    this.menuIcon = __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_jquery___default.a(".site-header__menu-icon");
    this.menuContent = __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_jquery___default.a(".site-header__menu-content");
    this.events();
}

events() {
    this.menuIcon.click(this.toggleTheMenu.bind(this));
}

toggleTheMenu() {
    this.menuContent.toggleClass("site-header__menu-content--is-visible");
    this.siteHeader.toggleClass("site-header--is-expanded");
    this.menuIcon.toggleClass("site-header__menu-icon--close-x");
}
```

}

```
class RevealOnScroll {
constructor(els, offset) {
    this.itemsToReveal = els;
    this.offsetPercentage = offset;
    this.hideInitally();
    this.createWaypoints();
}

hideInitally() {
    this.itemsToReveal.addClass("reveal-item");
}

createWaypoints() {
    var that = this;
    this.itemsToReveal.each(function() {
        var currentItem = this;
        new Waypoint({
            element: currentItem,
            handler: function() {
                __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_jquery___default.a(currentItem).addClass("reveal-item--is-visible");
            },
            offset: that.offsetPercentage
        });
    });
}
```

}

```
class StickyHeader {
constructor() {
    this.lazyImages = __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_jquery___default.a(".lazyload");
    this.siteHeader = __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_jquery___default.a(".site-header");
    this.headerTriggerElement = __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_jquery___default.a(".large-hero__title");
    this.createHeaderWaypoint();
    this.pageSections = __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_jquery___default.a(".page-section");
    this.headerLinks = __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_jquery___default.a(".primary-nav a");
    this.createPageSectionWaypoints();
    this.addSmoothScrolling();
    this.refreshWaypoints();
}

refreshWaypoints() {
    this.lazyImages.load(function() {
        Waypoint.refreshAll();
    });
}

addSmoothScrolling() {
    this.headerLinks.smoothScroll();
}

createHeaderWaypoint() {
    var that = this;
    new Waypoint({
        element: this.headerTriggerElement[0],
        handler: function(direction) {
            if (direction === "down"){
                that.siteHeader.addClass("site-header--dark");
            }
            else {
                that.siteHeader.removeClass("site-header--dark");
            }
        }
    });
}

createPageSectionWaypoints() {
    var that = this;
    this.pageSections.each(function() {
        var currentPageSection = this;
        new Waypoint({
            element: currentPageSection,
            handler: function(direction) {
                if (direction === "down") {
                    var matchingHeaderLink = currentPageSection.getAttribute("data-matching-link");
                    that.headerLinks.removeClass("is-current-link")
                    __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_jquery___default.a(matchingHeaderLink).addClass("is-current-link");
                }
            },
            offset: "18%"
        });
        new Waypoint({
            element: currentPageSection,
            handler: function(direction) {
                if (direction === "up") {
                    var matchingHeaderLink = currentPageSection.getAttribute("data-matching-link");
                    that.headerLinks.removeClass("is-current-link")
                    __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_jquery___default.a(matchingHeaderLink).addClass("is-current-link");
                }
            },
            offset: "-40%"
        });
    });
}
```

}

```
class Modal {
constructor() {
    this.openModalButton = __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_jquery___default.a(".open-modal");
    this.modal = __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_jquery___default.a(".modal");
    this.closeModalButton = __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_jquery___default.a(".modal__close");
    this.events();
}

events() {
    //clicking the open modal button 
    this.openModalButton.click(this.openModal.bind(this));

    //clicking the X close modal button
    this.closeModalButton.click(this.closeModal.bind(this));

    //pushes any key
    __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_jquery___default.a(document).keyup(this.keyPressHandler.bind(this));
}

keyPressHandler(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
        this.closeModal();
    }
}

openModal() {
    this.modal.addClass("modal--is-visible");
    return false;
}

closeModal() {
    this.modal.removeClass("modal--is-visible");
}
```

}

Comment: What error are you getting when you are including that code?

Comment: [Uglify still doesn't support ES6](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/448). `uglify-es` seems to be a recent addition

Comment: The error message is too long for me to paste on here. But long story short, I was able to figure out it was those pieces of code above causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

you should run `gulp-babel` before `gulp-uglify`

[gulp-babel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel)

there is [babili](https://github.com/babel/babili), might be a good idea to check it out

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to run a transpilation step in between. Gulp uglify can't handle the new Javascript formats and you'll need a plugin like https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel to make sure everything is in a common es2015 format.

```
const babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('default', () => {
return gulp.src('src/app.js')
    .pipe(babel({
        presets: ['es2015']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: So for this udemy course we installed: 
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",

Not gulp-babel